# Webkit Scrollbar Works On Mac But Not Windows

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I desgined a simple custom scroll bar using the -webkit-scrollbar and it used to work but one day it just stopped working (On my Windows machine) in certain components. The scroll bar works as expected in my SearchComponent, but when I go to my HomeComponent it doesn't seem to work. But when I had to do some work on my mac I noticed that it was working in every component. I'm confused how the same code can work different on different machines.

[HomeComponent Scroll Bar On Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GveSc.png) -
[SearchComponent Scroll Bar On Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bTQc.jpg)

HomeComponent.html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scroll-box">
            <p>Upcoming Films</p>
            <div class="upcoming-films">
                <div class="upcoming-film" *ngFor="let film of upcomingFilmList; let i = index">
                    <app-upcoming-film-template
                        [upcomingFilm]="film"                      
                        class="upcoming-film-{{i}}"
                    ></app-upcoming-film-template>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

HomeComponent.scss

```
//container for upcoming films
.scroll-box {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 6.5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: .2vw solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}
//scrollbar
.upcoming-films ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;
}
.upcoming-films ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

SearchComponent.html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="search-bar">
            <label class="prompt">What did you watch?</label>
            <input class="input-enter" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchInput" name="searchInput" (keyup.enter)="onSearch()" (focus)="toggleSearchLabel()" required>
            <i (click)="toggleMoviesActive()" class="movies">Movies</i>
            <i (click)="toggleSeriesActive()" class="series">Series</i>
            <i (click)="toggleUsersActive()" class="users">Users</i>
            <a (click)="onSearch()">
                <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="scroll-box">
            <div class="searched-films">
                <app-searched-film-template
                    *ngFor="let film of translatedMovies"
                    [filmDetails]="film" 
                    (click)="onFilmClicked(film.Type, film.imdbID)" 
                    class="searched-film"
                ></app-searched-film-template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

SearchComponent.scss

```
//container for searched films
.scroll-box {
    padding-right: 6.5px;
    margin-right: 6.5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 94%;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    transition: .5s;
}
//contains all the searched films
.scroll-box.searched-films {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-color: #fff transparent;
    transition: .5s;
}
//scrollbar
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;
}
.scroll-box::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

I have 5 components total that use that scroll bar and it only works in the SearchComponent on my Windows machine nowhere else. On my mac in works in all 5 components.

Comment: Could this be a cacheing issue?

Comment: @AHaworth can you elaborate on caching issue? I'm not too familiar with caching on the front end.